# XNA - how to use the same key for different options?

Tags: c#, if-statement, xna, keyboard, enter

So I have this code: Variables:

```
    enum gameState
    {
        gameLoading,
        mainMenu,
        gameOptions,
        levelSelect,
        gamePlaying,
        gameOver
    }
```

In the `Update()` method:

```
        if (CurrentGameState == gameState.gameLoading)
        {
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.E))
            {
                graphics.ToggleFullScreen(); //?
            }
            graphics.ApplyChanges();
        }
        ...
        //gameState.gameLoading logic
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
        CurrentGameState = gameState.mainMenu;
```

So what I want is to have Enter pressed in `gameState.gameLoading` and both resolution is fullscreen and the `gameState` is equal to `mainMenu`. When in `gameState.mainMenu` the resolution can't be changed from fullscreen to windowed by pressing enter. How to achieve this? Maybe using list?

Comment: Your question is unclear, do you want to change the full screen and gamestate when you press enter?

Comment: Yes, that's what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have different classes for any `gameState` if they need to have different behaviours. This will ensure you that each `Update` affect only its own `gameState`.

Comment: @PowerUser - Im not sure how this answers your question at all, really what should happen is you should have a switch statement for your game states and then inside of this could can either have your logic, or point to a difference class as pinckerman has stated

Comment: Yes, as I have been commenting in another of my XNA questions, I do have a `switch` statement for the `gameStates` in my code. Also as I mentioned above `//gameState.gameLoading logic` I meant. The first `case` in my `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already decided what the states of your game are, why don't use the State Machine design pattern to control your input handling behaviour?
This pattern's agenda is to delegate the work from the actual object to its states. What you do is create a class with an Update() method for each state like pinckerman suggested, and enter all the input handling + state transition logic there. You can find an example here: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state.
When I use it, I detach the context from it's states and transitions completly by using an abstract state class and inherit from it. This makes it easier to change the state machine if needed.
Here is a quick example:

```
public class Context
{
    private GameState state;

    public void Update()
    {
         state.Update();
    }

    public void ChangeState(GameState nextState)
    {
         state = nextState;
    }
}

public abstract class GameState
{
    protected Context context;

    public virtual void Update()
    {
        // some basic implementation if you want.
    }
}

public class GameLoadingState : GameState
{
    public override void Update()
    {
        // Handle key presses.
        context.ChaneState(new MainMenuState(context));
    }
}

public class MainMenuState : GameState
{
    public override void Update()
    {
        // Handle key presses in some other way.
        // Change state if needed.
    }
}
```

Again, if you don't like the implementation of the passive context, you can change it to be more active.
Hope this helps!